# Exportar tabela HTML para Excel dinâmica com o usuário

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, microsoft-excel, table

Tenho uma tabela em html onde o usuário vai colocar os valores, após informar os valores nessa tabela, devo exportar como excel.

Atualmente o código está exportando somente os valores "th", não consigo identificar como pegar os valores digitados pelo usuário, já li as publicações relacionada ao assunto, mas todos que achei passam valores "fixo".

```
<body>
    <div>
        <table id="tblExport">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Mês e Ano</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input id="mes_ano_1" placeholder ="dd/mm/yyyy" type="text" name="mes_ano">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input id="mes_ano_2" placeholder ="dd/mm/yyyy" type="text" name="mes_ano">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            <div>
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Nome</th>
                            <th>Produto</th>
                            <th>Quantidade</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <input id="num_vidas_1" placeholder ="Nome" type="text" name="info_nome">
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input id="vl_sinis_1" placeholder ="Nome do Produto" type="text" name="info_prod">
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input id="vl_copay_1" placeholder ="Quantidade vendida" type="text" name="info_qntd">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <input id="num_vidas_11" placeholder ="Nome" type="text" name="info_nome">
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input id="vl_sinis_11" placeholder ="Nome do Produto" type="text" name="info_prod">
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input  id="vl_copay_11" placeholder ="Quantidade vendida" type="text" name="info_qntd">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </table>
        <br><br>
        <button id="btnExport">Export to excel</button>
    </div>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.btechco.excelexport.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.base64.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
          $("#btnExport").click(function () {
              $("#tblExport").btechco_excelexport({
                  containerid: "tblExport"
                 , datatype: $datatype.Table
                 , filename: 'sample'
              });
          });
      });
    </script>   
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode tentar fazer o seguinte, crie um formulário em separado da tabela, quando você clicar em exportar ele primeiro copia o que foi informado no formulário para a tabela e depois exporta. Fiz um pequeno exemplo:

```html
<html>
 <body>
      
  <form>
   <label>Mês e Ano 1</label>
   <input id="form_mes_ano_1" placeholder ="dd/mm/yyyy" type="text" name="mes_ano">
   <hr>
   
   <label>Mês e Ano 2</label>   
   <input id="form_mes_ano_2" placeholder ="dd/mm/yyyy" type="text" name="mes_ano">
   <hr>
   
   <button id="btnExport">Exportar</button>
  </form>
     <div>
          <table id="tblExport">
             <thead>
                <tr>
                   <th>Mês e Ano</th>
                </tr>
             </thead>
             <tbody>
                <tr>
                   <td id="mes_ano_1">*</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                   <td id="mes_ano_2">*</td>
                </tr>
             </tbody>
          </table>
      
  </div>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery.btechco.excelexport.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery.base64.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnExport").click(function (event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   //Copiar do formulário para a tabela
   $('#mes_ano_1').html($('#form_mes_ano_1').val());
   $('#mes_ano_2').html($('#form_mes_ano_2').val());
            $("#tblExport").btechco_excelexport({
                containerid: "tblExport"
               , datatype: $datatype.Table
               , filename: 'formulario'
            });
        });
    });
  </script>   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ainda não :c, o excel continua vindo vazio